# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 46545

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, layout, adapter

Does anybody know a WORKING solution? None of the other threads helped.

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        
        binding.mainRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        
        adapter = MainRecyclerAdapter(this, null)
        binding.mainRecyclerView.adapter = MainRecyclerAdapter(this, null)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.mainRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        
        adapter = MainRecyclerAdapter(this, null)
        binding.mainRecyclerView.adapter = MainRecyclerAdapter(this, null)
```

when you use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)  , you must pass the root view to  `setContentView()`

Comment: Thank you very much 